# not to set Hyperlink when NavigateUri is null

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, textblock

I am using `Hyperlink` in `TextBlock`. The problem I am facing is when `NavigateUri` is null, I don't want to set `Hyperlink` or use default style, so that there is no difference between `TextBlock` and `Hyperlink`. How to do this?

The code that I am using is this:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
  <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Href}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Body}"/>
  </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Sometimes `Href`  is null. That time I don't have to set `NavigateUri`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I used is using DataTrigger to check Href value, if is equals to Null, set the related properties to imitate TextBlock's style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Href}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
```

**Null value:**

[image: Null value]

**!Null Value:**

[image: !Null Value]